# How to fix picture being flipped horizontally?

Tags: html, css

When I display certain images (specifically those with a larger height than width), they are flipped horizontally (90deg). Is this a bug in HTML?

[image: flipped image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>This is my code</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <img width="500px" src="testpicture.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Explain briefly so that we can understand.

Comment: please add a demo fiddle

Comment: also provide whole code in which image is actually flipping

Comment: Image taken with phone? If yes check exif metadata, maybe the photo itself is rotated and windows can't recognize correct orientation.

Comment: I added a link to a photo at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it flips not the image itself but the page as a whole due to the viewport setting. You can check that by adding text and watching whether the whole page turns 90 degrees.

Comment: I checked. It's not the page being flipped.

Comment: Sometimes it is the picture itself. Depending on your software, it may not actually rotate the image but set a view-mode tag. I would try to rotate the image in different software.